# Requirement already satisfied with psutil

Tags: python, pip, conda, psutil

I´m trying to install the lib psutil, using the command !pip install psutil. When I run this code, I got this

```
Requirement already satisfied: psutil in /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages (5.4.8)
```

After that, I try to run this code:

```
from plotly.offline import iplot, init_notebook_mode
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import plotly.io as pio

import os
import numpy as np

init_notebook_mode(connected=True)

N = 100
x = np.random.rand(N)
y = np.random.rand(N)
colors = np.random.rand(N)
sz = np.random.rand(N)*30

fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_scatter(x=x,
                y=y,
                mode='markers',
                marker={'size': sz,
                        'color': colors,
                        'opacity': 0.6,
                        'colorscale': 'Viridis'
                       });
iplot(fig)

pio.write_image(fig, 'fig1.png')
```

And it works! But at the end of the code, when I try to save the picture, I got this error:

```
ValueError: Image generation requires the psutil package.

Install using pip:
    $ pip install psutil

Install using conda:
    $ conda install psutil
```

What can I do to install the lib psutil?

I also try to install using conda install psutil and got this:

```
==> WARNING: A newer version of conda exists. <==                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
  current version: 4.5.8                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
  latest version: 4.5.11                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   

Please update conda by running                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             

    $ conda update -n base conda                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           



# All requested packages already installed.
```

But if I use conda update -n base conda, nothing happend!

Comment: the conda error is unrelated to the `psutil`, and has already been discussed e.g. here https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/6941. A solution that worked for me was to specify the base channel with `conda update -n base conda -c anaconda`

Answer (score 0):

I have stumbled upon this issue related to `psutil` installation recently, and I saw many different ways of installing this python module. I'm not sure which way will work for you, but you should try these options:

`$ pip3 install psutil`

or

`$ python -m pip install psutil`

or

`$ python3 -m pip install psutil`

As for the `conda` packet manager update error, I've never seen this error before, so maybe doing a fresh installation should solve this issue.

[Miniconda installer](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html)

[Anaconda installer](https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/)

Comment: Besides install the lib, I needed reload my jupyter notebook (ubuntu 20)